# Python Dataframe. Move rows values left according index of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the table like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[20, 15, 10, 5], [20, 15, 10, 5], [20, 15, 10, 5], [20, 15, 10, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
df
```

| one | two | three | four |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 |

I want to move every rows values left according their rows index.
Row values with index 0 stays the same, Row values with index 1 moves left in one point, Row values with index 2 moves left in two points, etc...
Desired table should looks like this:

| one | two | three | four |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 |
| 15 | 10 | 5 | 0 |
| 10 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way by using a simple loop to [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) the values in every row, and then use
[`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to replace **NA** values with **0**:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.iloc[i,:] = df.iloc[i,:].shift(-i)

df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df
   one   two  three  four
0   20  15.0   10.0   5.0
1   15  10.0    5.0   0.0
2   10   5.0    0.0   0.0
3    5   0.0    0.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a method that shift left regarding the index value and fills with 0

```py
import pandas as pd


def rotate_row(row):
    return pd.Series(row.to_list()[row.name:] + [0] * row.name, index=row.index)


data = [[20, 15, 10, 5], [20, 15, 10, 5], [20, 15, 10, 5], [20, 15, 10, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
df = df.apply(rotate_row, axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
   one  two  three  four
0   20   15     10     5
1   15   10      5     0
2   10    5      0     0
3    5    0      0     0
```

Comment: Works fine) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An upper right triangle to upper left triangle approach:

Create a mask to grab the upper triangle of the DataFrame using [`np.triu`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html#numpy-triu) + [`np.ones`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html#numpy-ones) + [`DataFrame.shape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html#pandas-dataframe-shape)

```
mask = np.triu(np.ones(df.shape, dtype=bool))
```

```
[[ True  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True]
 [False False  True  True]
 [False False False  True]]
```

Grab corresponding values from the [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas-dataframe-values) of the DataFrame:

```
a = df.values[mask]
```

```
[20 15 10  5 15 10  5 10  5  5]
```

Create a [`np.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html#numpy-zeros) skeleton of the same `dtype` as `a` and [`fliplr`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy.fliplr) the mask and assign back:

```
tri = np.zeros(df.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
tri[np.fliplr(mask)] = a
```

```
[[20 15 10  5]
 [15 10  5  0]
 [10  5  0  0]
 [ 5  0  0  0]]
```

Turn back into a DataFrame:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(tri, columns=df.columns)
```

`new_df`:

```
   one  two  three  four
0   20   15     10     5
1   15   10      5     0
2   10    5      0     0
3    5    0      0     0
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [[20, 15, 10, 5], [20, 15, 10, 5], [20, 15, 10, 5],
        [20, 15, 10, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])

mask = np.triu(np.ones(df.shape, dtype=bool))
a = df.values[mask]
tri = np.zeros(df.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
tri[np.fliplr(mask)] = a
new_df = pd.DataFrame(tri, columns=df.columns)
print(new_df)
```